# Can't seem to get [shortcode]s to work

Tags: shortcode

```
function register_shortcodes(){
    add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode' );
    }
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes'); 
function my_shortcode( $atts ) {
    return "--my_shortcode--";
    }
```

Adding this code to a plugin I've been making (specifically for this) doesn't do anything. I don't think the function `my_shortcode( $atts )` is even called.

I've tried putting "`[my_shortcode]`" in posts, comments, template(s).php. `return "--my_shortcode--";` never executes.

I've also put the above piece of code in `functions.php` which gives me error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_shortcode() in C:\localhost\~\wp-includes\functions.php on line 17
```

line 17 : `add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode' );`

Comment: [`functions.php` is a file within your current theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained), not the `functions.php` file in `wp-includes`. there's nothing wrong with your code as-is as long as it's in a file that's actually being loaded at the correct time.

Comment: @Milo Thank you! It works now from the theme's function.php. Any idea how could I put it into my plugin code and make it work? Or is that simply not possible?

Answer (score 1):

As Milo indicated:

> [`functions.php` is a file within your current
>   theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained), not the
>   `functions.php` file in `wp-includes`. There's nothing wrong with your
>   code as-is as long as it's in a file that's actually being loaded at
>   the correct time.

Addressing your other question from the comments, yes, this code can be wrapped up into a plugin file. Once the plugin has been activated, you'd just need to place your `[my_shortcode]` shortcode within a post/page content area, and it will be executed.