# How to handle shortcodes through plugin

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

[I learned that I can only put in the code for handling my shortcode through the theme's `functions.php`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100004/cant-seem-to-get-shortcodes-to-work)

But I was thinking of making it a plugin rather than a theme. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference. This is a complete shortcode plugin:

```
/* Plugin Name: blogname */
add_shortcode( 'blogname', 'get_bloginfo' );
```

Usually, you should never register shortcodes in a theme, because the content will be useless after a a theme switch. So, a plugin is the better option.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm a dumbass x_x (it's somehow working now)

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with toscho but I would use a [must-use plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) in this case. In this way nothing will prevent shortcode from executing because Must-Use plugins can not be deactivated through WordPress admin.

Comment: I disagree. Must-use plugins should be reserved for very few use cases: super-important functionality that keeps the site running. Shortcodes don’t fall under this category.

Comment: That' s kinda a point. But if plugin is deactivated or if function is deleted in functions.php you'll get [shortcode] on your posts. That's what you want ?

Comment: It is ugly, but not critical. On the other hand: when a shortcode callback returns an error message after an upgrade, you probably want to turn it off fast.

Comment: "not critical" < depends. I mean ok this would not take the site down but let's say you use more than 1 shortcode in your post this could be hard for reading not to mention UX.